# Qt Stylesheets with derived classes

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qwidget

Can I use Qt stylesheets with a derived widget?  I'd like to be able to define some custom properties on the widget (like various colors) and be able to define their value in a stylesheet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just declare your properties with [Q_PROPERTY](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/properties.html).

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( int fun READ getFun WRITE setFun )
    public:
    MyClass( QObject * parent=0, const char * name=0 );
    ~MyClass();

    void setFun( int x );
    int getFun() const;
};
```