# CSS Stylesheet is not applied to custom QWidget

Tags: qt, widget, qtstylesheets

What I'm trying to do is to apply custom CSS to a custom widget deriving from `QLabel` but I'm having no luck.

I have the custom class defined as:

```
class CustomLabel : public QLabel {

}
```

I've not re-implemented the `paintEvent` function as I thought that given that the standard `QLabel` supports CSS stylesheets, I would just need to refer to this new widget in CSS, for example:

```
CustomLabel {
    background-color: #111111;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Unfortunately at run-time, no style is applied the `CustomLabel` and the default `QLabel` style is applied.

Can anyone suggest why my CSS rules are being ignored for `CustomLabel`?

**Steps to Recreate**

1. Create a Qt Widgets project using Qt Creator
2. Add a custom class derived from `QLabel` and call it `CustomLabel`
3. Add a `QLabel` onto a form using the designer
4. Promote the label to a `CustomLabel` class
5. Apply the stylesheet using the following code in `main.cpp`:

   ```
   a.setStyleSheet("CustomLabel {font-weight: bold;}");
   ```
6. Run the program and notice how `CustomLabel` is not styled in accordance with the CSS style.

Comment: If you CustomLabel has namespace, you need to add that namespace to your css. Refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206492/qt-stylesheet-in-derived-class-in-c-namespace-selector

Answer (score 2):

You should use the macro `Q_OBJECT` inside your `CustomLabel` definition, otherwise `CustomLabel` is not known to Qt's type system:

```
class CustomLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT
}
```

**MCVE**

CustomLabel.h:

```
#include "QLabel"
class CustomLabel : public QLabel {
  Q_OBJECT
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "QApplication"
#include "CustomLabel.h"
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  a.setStyleSheet("CustomLabel {font-weight: bold; background-color: red;}");

  CustomLabel label;
  label.setText ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua");
  label.show ();

  a.exec ();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried this and it made no difference.

Comment: I have added a [mcve]. This works for me using Qt 5.9.

Comment: Hmm, interesting - I'm using 5.9.1 and it doesn't work for me. I've done a `clean`, run `qmake` and `build`

Comment: This answer is correct, though in my case the additional problem was the incorrect assumption that the derived class name (here `CustomLabel`) is more specific than the base (here `QLabel`). In practice their specificity is the same. This makes the CSS entry for `CustomLabel` to apply only if it's specified below the one for `QLabel`. See details in Qt description of [Conflict Resolution](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#conflict-resolution).

Answer (score 1):

Try settings `Qt::WA_StyledBackground` attribute for your custom label.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've managed to find a "workaround" rather than a proper answer: use the `accessibleName` parameter.

So in Qt Creator, assign a value such as `CustomLabel` to the `accessibleName` field of the `QLabel` and in the CSS file, add the following:

```
QLabel[accessibleName="CustomLabel"] {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: accessibleName is a property of QWidget. It can be changed.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#accessibleName-prop

Comment: For such a workaround you'd better set object name via `myLabel -> setObjectName("customLabel");`, and then access it in the CSS via `QLabel#customLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

As [pat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8106002/pat) mentioned above in a short comment, you have to look out for your namespaces too, and mark them in the CSS file.
In your case the CSS snippet should look like follows if the class is embedded in the UI namespace:

```
UI--CustomLabel {
    background-color: #111111;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```